# Number of patients in ICUs

Tags: probability, statistics

During the past 50 days we observed the number of Covid patients in the city's hospitals and the records show a mean $μ = 710$ and $σ = 151$.

Calculate the probability to have more than 950 patients in ICUs.

We want to find $P(X>950)$.

We calculate $Z = \frac{950-710}{\sqrt 151} = 19.53$

but I don't think it is correct.

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you are confusing variance, $\sigma^2$, with standard deviation, $\sigma$.

Comment: This is a poorly formulated question. Since ICU patients typically spend more than one day there, the numbers of patients on different days are far from independent.  So the standard deviation of the observed data should not be interpreted as the standard deviation of a distribution for the number of patients on some other day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $z$-score in this case is $$z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma }=\frac{950-710}{151}=1.59$$
Then we can simply calculate $\mathbb P(Z>1.59)$ assuming normal data.